# Добавление и трансформация изображения на другое изображение

Tags: python, pillow

столкнулся с проблемой - не знаю как трансформировать изображение по точкам и добавить на другое изображение уже трансформированное.
Любая фотография представляет из себя некоторый четырехугольник и меня интересует изменить расположение точек образующих этот четырехугольник и разместить фотографию на другой фотографии, ниже прикреплю пример.

Я использую python и pillow, пока что не получилось добиться требуемого результата

[image: Пример конечного изображения]

Comment: покажите в вопросе, как вы используете python и pillow

Comment: @strawdog 
`
def transform_image(background_image_path, layout_image_path, output_image_path, *points):
    back_img = Image.open(background_image_path)
    lay_img = Image.open(layout_image_path)
    x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = points
    new_points = [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]
    lay_img = lay_img.transform(lay_img.size, Image.QUAD, new_points, Image.BICUBIC)
    back_img.paste(lay_img)
    back_img.save(output_image_path)

transform_image(background_image_path, layout_image_path, output_image_path, 0, 100, 50, 150, 200, 50, 250)
`

Comment: код должен быть в вопросе, а не в комментарии.